# adding static list to a dictionary cause original list updated

Tags: c#

I have static decimal list.

```
public static List<decimal> E_18_BasCevresi = new List<decimal> { 45.6m, 46.5m, 47.4m, 48.4m, 49.4m, 50.3m, 51.2m };
```

I add this list to the dictionary

```
public Dictionary<string, List<decimal>> BasCevresi { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<decimal>>();

BasCevresi.Add("mylabel", E_18_BasCevresi);
...
BasCevresi["mylabel"].Add(15);//though just adding the list of "mylabel" not origin static list
```

It works as expected, but when I use static `E_18_BasCevresi` variable anywhere else it contains the value 15, its not suppose to be in my origin static list?

Why this value added to origin list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List is a reference value, when you add the list to the dictionary any change to the list is reflected in the original list, and this is why the static E_18_BasCevresi list contains the value 15.
In order to solve that you need to insert to the dictionary a copy of the list like this:

```
BasCevresi.Add("mylabel", new List<decimal>(E_18_BasCevresi));
```